# cakePHP validation errors not showing

Tags: validation, cakephp

So basically I have a **view** action in my users controller where the user can modify his information(username,first name, last name, email..) this form sends to another **update** action which does the saving stuff, problem is that when I submit the form and one or more fields don't meet the validation rules it doesn't show underneath each fields but the data doesn't save and

> $this->User->validationErrors

outputs the errors.

my update action (accessed after submiting the form on view.ctp)

view.ctp:

```
<?php

        echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'div' => 'form-group',
                'wrapInput' => false,
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ),
            'class' => 'well',
            'url'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'update'),
            'id'=>'info-form'
        ));
        ?>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Information</legend>

            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('id', array('value' => $userinfo['User']['id']));
            echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array(
                'label' => 'Username',
                'value'=>$userinfo['User']['username']
            ));
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->error('username'); ?></td>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array(
                'label' => 'E-mail',
                'value'=>$userinfo['User']['email']
            ));
            ?>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.fname', array(
                'label' => 'First name',
                'value'=>$userinfo['User']['fname']
            ));
            ?>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.lname', array(
                'label' => 'Last name',
                'value'=>$userinfo['User']['lname']
            ));
            ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->submit('Update', array(
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success'
        ));
        ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

update function:

```
function update() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Information updated Successfuly.'), 'alert', array(
                        'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                        'class' => 'alert-success'), 'success');
                    return $this->redirect('/users/view/' . $this->request->data['User']['id']);
                } else {
                    // $errors = $this->User->validationErrors; var_dump($errors);die;
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('An error occured'), 'alert', array(
                        'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                        'class' => 'alert-danger'), 'danger');
                    return $this->redirect('/users/view/' . $this->request->data['User']['id']);
                }

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Request was not of POST type.'), 'alert', array(
                'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                'class' => 'alert-danger'), 'danger');
            return $this->redirect('/users/index/');
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're redirecting after - that will make it lose the validation warnings.

Comment: How am I supposed to do this then?

Comment: @user3813360 - That's an all-together different question.  Feel free to ask it here on StackOverflow, and I'm sure you'll get some great answers.

Comment: Give this man a medal. i was looking for this solution so desperately. everythings working so perfect now. greatly thanx!